# How to swipe activity Android

Tags: android

I have two activity, Activity1 and Activity2. which are activity1.xml = Activity1.java and activity2.xml = Activity2.java
Now I am at activity1.xml and just by swiping with my finger from right to left I want to go to the second activity2.xml.
I don't want to use ScrollView. The example of this like when you are on "Apps" menu (Android Phone) if you swipe from right to left it goes to "widgets" menu

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will setup a single Activity, that will contain 2 fragments.  In the Activity, you will use a ViewPager to swipe between the 2 fragments.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Thank you, you both helped me

Answer (score 1):

It is still the same activity. And you are talking about ViewPager widget.